# Filter custom ArrayAdapter or implement search in activity

Tags: android, mysql, listview, search, adapter

I have successfully implemented listview from MYSQL database with the help of a tutorial using Adapter. Now I need to add a filter to the displayed listview or some kind of search dialog. I am really new to android. I want to search the database and display the result in the next activity. A detailed explanation will be so much appreciated. I know how to invoke the search dialog but i am notable to proceed ahead. Here is the activity which consist of the databse in listview:

**DBLib.java**

```
    package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class DBLib extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private Button b_search;
    private EditText et;

    private static final String READ_DB_URL ="http://crshaggy.byethost7.com/webservice/warehouse.php";

    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

    private JSONArray mComments = null;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dblib_list);
        b_search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.listsearch);
        b_search.setOnClickListener(this);






    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onSearchRequested();

    }


        @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        // loading the comments via AsyncTask
        new LoadComments().execute();
    }

    public void updateJSONdata() {

    mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_DB_URL);

    try{
        mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);

        mCommentList.add(map);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void updateList() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList, 
        R.layout.post, new String[] { TAG_TITLE, TAG_ID}, 
        new int[] { R.id.title});

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                    }
                });
            }

    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DBLib.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Warehouse...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            updateJSONdata();
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            updateList();
        }
    }




    }
```

**Layout of list**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/customgrey"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.DBLib" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/listsearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/searchbutton" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listsearch" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit 1**
I have updated my code a bit I have added a onTextChanged() method but it is giving a null pointer exception. I have just changed the OnPostCreate() method which I am posting here:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            updateList();

            inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_search);

            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    DBLib.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
            });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleAdapter already comes enabled with filtering capabilities.  You'll just need to invoke something like:

```
getListAdapter().getFilter().filter("Text to search for");
```

That's it.  Android will handle filtering through your data and displaying those that match the given string.

**Update - Custom Filter**

To customize how the filter searches is a lot more involved.  The short answer, you'll need to write your own version of the SimpleAdapter.  AFAIK, none of the Android provided adapters provide an easy solution for how to customize the filtering logic.  It's why I am building up [Advanced-Adapters](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters), unfortunately I haven't written a solution for the SimpleAdapter yet. It's all ArrayAdapter and SparseArray alternatives right now.

You'll probably find lots of people and examples saying to extend the SimpleAdapter class and override the `getFilter()` method to have it return a new Filter class implemented by you.  You can then use your `mCommentList` arraylist to figure out how to filter the data.  While this will work in some situations, it's the incorrect approach and will fail for various cases.

The correct solution is to create your own adapter class that behaves like SimpleAdapter but extends the BaseAdapter class...which basically means create your own adapter from scratch.  Being new to Android, it can be a very daunting task and there's a lot to learn and understand on how adapters work.

The easiest way to do this would be to literally copy the SimpleAdapter [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java/) into your project and then manually change the filter code's logic to how you want it.  The logic to adjust specifically occurs within [this for loop](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#345).  Keep in mind, that's within the `performFiltering()` method which is on a background thread! Hence all the synchronized blocks.

Comment: Please have a look at the Edit!

Comment: You reference `DBLib.this.adapter` but I don't see where you define it. Assuming that `onPostExecute` is still in DBLib, you can just call `DBLib.this.getListAdapter()` directly.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked now. I now have another issue. when i write anything in edittext to filter, it just filters the first word before I input space. If there is something after space, the activity goes blank and the list goes away. Basically it is just filering the first word which i input

Comment: Yup, you can customize how the filter behaves but that's a little bit more involved.  Will update my answer later tonight for how to do that.

Comment: Looking forward to it! Thanks

Comment: Thank You so much @Jay. Pls have a look at this too: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197928/error-posting-json-data-from-android/25197974#25197974]